# Help with back reference regex in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, backreference

I am trying to write a regular expression in vi to match any whitespace character followed by any digit. Then, at each match, insert a dollar sign between the whitespace and the digit. Here is an example:

```
A1234 12 14 B1234
B1256 A2 14 C1245
C1234 34 D1 1234K
```

The correct regex would produce this:

```
A1234 $12 $14 B1234
B1256 A2 14 C1245
C1234 $34 D1 $1234K
```

I realize I need to use a back reference, but I can't quite seem to write the correct regex. Here is my attempt:

```
:'<,'>/(\s\d)/\s\1\$/g
```

Also, I have Vim's default regex mode turned off (`vnoremap / /\v`).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why the number `14` in the second line of the correct result example is not prepended with `$`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses to make them work as groupings rather than as actual matches in the text, and *not* escape the $. Like so:

```
:%s/\(\s\)\(\d\)/\1$\2/g
```

This worked for me in vim (using standard magic setting).

**Edit**: just realized that your non-standard regex settings cause you having the escape 'the other way around'. But still, the trick, I think, is to use two groups. With your settings, this should work:

```
:%s/(\s)(\d)/\1$\2/g
```

Comment: There is no need to escape `$` sign in the replacement part of the `:substitute` command even in "magic" mode.

Answer (score 6):

Using a back reference is not inevitable.  One can make a pattern to match
zero-width text between a whitespace character and a digit, and replace that
empty interval with `$` sign.

```
:'<,'>s/\s\zs\ze\d/$/g
```

(See `:help /\zs` and `:help /\ze` for details about the atoms changing the
borders of a match.)

Comment: @sidyll: "Correct"? Is there some standards document I have missed?

Comment: Sorry @Johnsyweb, I didn't want to sound this bad. Not because it's documented, but because this one is much cleaner by using features mostly seen in Vim only (\ze and \zs).

Comment: @sidyll:  Thanks, I feel the same way!  Sometimes people value trickery more than elegance, though.  (Like here or in [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495932/how-can-i-trim-blank-lines-at-the-end-of-file-in-vim).)

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is:

```
:%s/(\b\d)/$\1/g
```

with `\b` is for word boundary. But it turns out that `\b` doesn't mean word boundary in Vim regex, rather `\<` and `\>` for the start and end of the word. So the right answer would be:

```
:%s/\(\<\d\)/$\1/g
```

(Making sure to escape the capturing parenthesis.)

Sorry that my correction came so late.

Comment: I'm trying to do the substitution on a visual block, so I did `:'<,'>s/(\s\d)/$\1/g`, but it didn't work. I get a `Pattern not found` error with either `\b` or `\s`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have opportunity to test it where I am, I'll look into it later.

Comment: IIRC `\b` is backspace, not word boundary.

Comment: Hmm ... it is word boundary for `sed` regex, but not for Vim, apparantly.

Comment: 'the great thing about standards...'

Comment: worst thing about regex is every implementation has a different flavour. got asked in phone interview to produce a regex for ip addresses once....must have been the dumbest question ever asked.

Comment: @sashang, `.*` will work in pretty much any regex impl... and matches *almost* anything :P

Comment: @JeenBroekstra yeah i realize that there's a common subset of tokens that works in any implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure abt the exact vim syntax, but regEx syntax should be this:

```
search expr - "(\s)([\d])"
replacement expr - "\1 $\2"
```

so something like:

```
/(\s)([\d])/\1 $\2/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you (without using groups):

```
:%s/\s\@<=\d\@=/$/g
```

Explanation:

- [`%`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3a%25): On every line...
- [`s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3as): Substitute...
- `/`: Start of pattern
- [`\s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cs): Whitespace
- [`\@<=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@%3C=): Match behind (zero-width)
- [`\d`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cd): Digit
- [`\@=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@=): Require match (zero-width)
- `/`: End of pattern, start of replacement
- `$`: What you asked for!
- `/`: End of replacement
- [`g`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3as_flags): Replace all occurrences in the line.