# Astyle is adding new lines to the end of the file everytime

Tags: c++, c, vim, autoformatting, astyle

I just installed vim-autoformat and astyle to format my c/c++ code inside vim. Everything seems to work, but it puts a newline to the end of the file everytime I run it. Even if there is one (or multiple). I tried to find the option in astyle -h and search the web, but didn't find anything. What do I do?

Comment: temporary hack: write wrapper calling astyle and [trimming whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495932/how-can-i-trim-blank-lines-at-the-end-of-file-in-vim)

Comment: So... if you run astyle 5 times you end up with 5 blank lines at the end of the buffer? Or 5 EOL chars at the end of the last line?

Comment: I'll try it.. and @romainl Yes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a bug in astyle that's been fixed.  See http://astyle.sourceforge.net/subversion.html for help getting the latest development version.   I'm using version 2.05 beta and it seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: Indeed, the latest svn builds don't have this issue.